# oci_bind_by_name and to_date PHP/OCI/Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface, ora-01858

I have the following:

```
    $ARTIFACT_NAME = $_POST['ArtifactName'];
    $ARTIFACT_TYPE = $_POST['ArtifactType'];
    $ARTIFACT_LOCATION = $_POST['ArtifactLocation'];
    $ARTIFACT_DOMAIN = $_POST['ArtifactDomain'];
    $ARTIFACT_AUTHOR = $_POST['ArtifactAuthor'];
    $ARTIFACT_LABEL = 'DB_'.$ARTIFACT_LOCATION.'_'.$ARTIFACT_DOMAIN.'_'.$ARTIFACT_NAME;
    $AUDIT_CONSTRAINTS = $_POST['AuditConstraints'];
    $SECURITY_CONSTRAINTS = $_POST['SecurityConstraints'];
    $REGISTERED_EMAIL = $_SERVER['HTTP_REMOTE_USER'];
    $REGISTERED_TIMESTAMP = "to_date('15-08-2011 14:32:37', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')";

    $query =    "INSERT INTO ".$db_schema.".ARTIFACTS (ARTIFACT_ID, ARTIFACT_NAME, ARTIFACT_TYPE, ARTIFACT_LOCATION, ARTIFACT_DOMAIN, ARTIFACT_AUTHOR, ARTIFACT_LABEL, AUDIT_CONSTRAINTS, SECURITY_CONSTRAINTS, REGISTERED_EMAIL, REGISTERED_TIMESTAMP)
                VALUES (:bind1, :bind2, :bind3, :bind4, :bind5, :bind6, :bind7, :bind8, :bind9, :bind10, :bind11)";
    $statement = oci_parse($connection, $query);

    oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":bind1", $ARTIFACT_ID);
    oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":bind2", $ARTIFACT_NAME);
    oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":bind3", $ARTIFACT_TYPE);
    oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":bind4", $ARTIFACT_LOCATION);
    oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":bind5", $ARTIFACT_DOMAIN);
    oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":bind6", $ARTIFACT_AUTHOR);
    oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":bind7", $ARTIFACT_LABEL);
    oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":bind8", $AUDIT_CONSTRAINTS);
    oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":bind9", $SECURITY_CONSTRAINTS);
    oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":bind10", $REGISTERED_EMAIL);
    oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":bind11", $REGISTERED_TIMESTAMP);
```

Which gives the following error:

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

However, if i just don't bind `$REGISTERED_TIMESTAMP` and insert the `to_date` into the `$query` directly - it works perfectly.

What's going on?! This is drving me mad!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using an Oracle statement with bound parameters. That's good because it prevents SQL injections where dangerous code is inserted into your SQL statement. However, in this case, it prevents the `TO_CHAR` function from being executed. Instead, it tries to convert the whole string into a timestamp, which of course doesnt' work.

The solution is rather straight-forward: move to `TO_CHAR` function away from the bound parameter directly into the statement:

```
$REGISTERED_TIMESTAMP = "15-08-2011 14:32:37";

$query =    "INSERT INTO ".$db_schema.".ARTIFACTS (ARTIFACT_ID, ARTIFACT_NAME, ARTIFACT_TYPE, ARTIFACT_LOCATION, ARTIFACT_DOMAIN, ARTIFACT_AUTHOR, ARTIFACT_LABEL, AUDIT_CONSTRAINTS, SECURITY_CONSTRAINTS, REGISTERED_EMAIL, REGISTERED_TIMESTAMP)
            VALUES (:bind1, :bind2, :bind3, :bind4, :bind5, :bind6, :bind7, :bind8,
               :bind9, :bind10, to_date(:bind11, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))";
```

Comment: Saved possible hours of frustration. Thank you mate. :)