# PHP oci_execute(): ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Tags: php, oracle

I'm trying to insert data from php to oracle

but I have error  `oci_execute(): ORA-01008: not all variables bound`

Note: insert some data not all filed in table.

```
$sql =  'INSERT INTO LIC_WEB_VIOLATIONS (VIO_CODE, LIC_CODE, LIC_NO , NOTES, PAID_FLAG, AUDIT_FLAG, TYPE, STATUS, LIC_TYPE, OWNER_ID, CREATION_DATE, CREATION_USER_ID) 
VALUES(:VIO_CODE, :LIC_CODE, :LIC_NO, :NOTES, :PAID_FLAG, :AUDIT_FLAG, :TYPE, :STATUS, :LIC_TYPE, :OWNER_ID, :CREATION_DATE , :CREATION_USER_ID)';

$stid = oci_parse($objConnect, $sql);

oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':VIO_CODE', $VioCode);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':LIC_CODE', $Lic_Code);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':LIC_NO', $Lic_no);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':NOTES', $NOTES);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':PAID_FLAG', $PAID_FLAG);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':AUDIT_FLAG', $AUDIT_FLAG);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':TYPE', $TYPE);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':STATUS', $STATUS);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':LIC_TYPE', $LIC_TYPE);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':OWNER_ID', $IDNum);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':LIC_TYPE', $TimeNow);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':CREATION_USER_ID', $CREATION_USER_ID);

$r = oci_execute($stid);  // executes and commits

if ($r) {
    print "sucess VIOLATIONS";
}

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($objConnect);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:LIC_TYPE` is bounded two times and `:CREATION_DATE` never:

Change:

```
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':LIC_TYPE', $LIC_TYPE);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':OWNER_ID', $IDNum);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':LIC_TYPE', $TimeNow);
```

To:

```
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':LIC_TYPE', $LIC_TYPE);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':OWNER_ID', $IDNum);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':CREATION_DATE', $TimeNow);
```

Comment: $DateToday = date("d/m/y");
when insert date --> error appeared to me 'ORA-01843: not a valid month'

Comment: @mohammadrababah see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066978/oci-bind-by-name-and-to-date-php-oci-oracle

Answer (score 1):

You missed `CREATION_DATE` pasted `LIC_TYPE` twice,change second last line

```
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':CREATION_DATE', $CREATION_DATE); // assume var name
```