# Oracle Where First and Last Day returned ORA-00904: "NOV": invalid identifier

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I'm pretty new in Oracle and I want count data from first day and last day of this month (dynamically).

My PHP code look like this :

```
$date = Date('d-M-y');

// Query
$query = "Select COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE CREATED 
          BETWEEN FIRST_DAY(TRUNC(TO_DATE(".$date."), 'MON')) AND 
                  LAST_DAY(TRUNC(TO_DATE(".$date."), 'MON'))";
```

But I always get the error

> ORA-00904: "NOV": invalid identifier

Which `NOV` is the correct month -right?

Comment: @user10089632 nope, it's not help me out :(

Comment: How about trying this `to_date(' " . $date . " ', 'DD-MON-YY')` in both places??

Comment: Use [bind parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php) - also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066978/oci-bind-by-name-and-to-date-php-oci-oracle)

Answer (score 3):

If you leave it to oracle you could use

```
$query = "Select COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MON') = TRUNC(CREATED,'MON')";
```

If you have an index on CREATED it could be faster to use

```
$query = "Select COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE CREATED >=  TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MON') AND CREATED < TRUNC(ADD_MONTH(SYSDATE,1),'MON')
```

Comment: ok good, i've voted up for the first statement, but in the second `TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,1),'MON')` yields '20171201' (as in the format yyyymmdd ), and should be excepted from the range.

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan, right, but only 20171201 00:00:00.000 is included. If this is a realistic date(or time part isn't saved) for the application it must be excluded extra.

Comment: Replaced bwtween with >= and <

Comment: ok, right, thank you. To think from the point of view of performance is very good, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for trying to answer, but i got this to solve my problem :

for get first day in month i used :

```
"TRUNC(TO_DATE('".$date."', 'DD-MM-YY'), 'MM')"
```

for last day, use :

```
"LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('".$date."', 'DD-MM-YY'))"
```